# NodeJS AWS SDK - see live logs (like --follow from AWS CLI)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

In **AWS CLI** there is an option to run

```
aws logs tail some-group --follow
```

To see live logs from some group.

I would like to achieve the same, ideally getting a `Readable` I could subscribe to using **NodeJS AWS SDK**. Is this possible?